# Scala List of Objects to comma separated String

Tags: java, scala, stream

From java.util.List[CustomObject] I want to remove value and create a comma separated string, tried the below code but got exception

snippet 1

```
def getVal(a_attribList: List[CustomObject]): String = a_attribList
    .stream()
    .map(new java.util.function.Function[CustomObject, String] {
        override def apply(CustomObject): String = {
            t.getNolumn
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

snippet 2

```
def getVal(a_attribList: List[CustomObject]): String = {
    a_attribList
        .stream()
        .map(a => a.getNolumn)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Exception

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[com.test.dataobjects.CustomObject,String]
 required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: com.test.dataobjects.CustomObject, _ <: R]
            .map(a => a.getNolumn)
                   ^
three errors found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ValentinCarnu already pointed out the snippets are using `scala.collection.immutable.List` instead of a `java.util.List`.
Thus, you only need to map it using an standar scala anonymous function, and then convert it to a String using the [**mkString** *method*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#mkString(sep:String):String)

```
def getVal(a_attribList: List[CustomObject]): String =
  a_attribList.map(a => a.getNolumn).mkString(",")
```

Now, if you really have a java List, you can [convert it to a Scala list](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) using the [**JavaConverters** *package*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html).

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def getVal(a_attribList: java.util.List[CustomObject]): String =
  a_attribList.asScala.map(a => a.getNolumn).mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 3):

Map all your string values and then call

```
.mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can covert it to scala List and do the mapping:

```
a_attribList.asScala.map(_.getNolumn).mkString(",")
```